# Website by ip address loads quickly, by domain on cloudflare, forever

Tags: gruntjs, cloudflare

When you go to my ip address (
    146.148.39.138
) the site loads blazingly fast, but when you go to the domain name (zanehitchcox.com), which is hosted on cloudflare, the resources take forever to load.

As you can see, the site is just a barebones angular-bootstrap app installed with yo and run by grunt. What's weird is the background loads immediately, I'm guessing because it's cached, but the text takes like 10 seconds to load.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140807_EE_52Y/1/details/   shows the site  not passing through CloudFlare is taking roughly 4.3 seconds to load, with a "Start Render" at 4.33 seconds.

Tests look to be all about the same (4.2 - 4.3 seconds or so):
    http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140807_JW_54R/
    http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140807_89_56S/
    http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140807_MH_56W/
    http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140807_AC_56X/

We'd be happy to look at things further if you'd be interested in re-enabling CloudFlare on your site. Just open up a support ticket with the specifics of what you're seeing when CloudFlare is enabled. Our support team can help.

p.s. I work at CloudFlare.